# Enabling input text on page load based on span value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page which consist of a `<span>` element and `<input>` element.
My requirement is to dynamically enabling/disabling the `<input>` element based on `<span>` innerHTML.

I have written following javascript:

```
var vale=document.getElementById("SPAN_ID").innerHTML;
```

But value is coming as `undefined`,since I guess at page loading span element is yet to be constructed.I have to **perform this operation on page loading time only**.Can anyone provide any suitable javascript code for this??

Comment: Can you show at least a piece of your structure

Comment: Just put your code on $(document).ready(function(){ ...your code goes here.. })

Comment: Can you please add the code blocks, so that I can help you better.

Comment: Are you testing `vale` or `value`? Because you are storing it in `vale`, so if you are testing `value`, of course it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event to wait for the HTML to be fully loaded and parsed before running your code:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var value = document.getElementById("the-span").innerHTML;

  if (value) {
    document.getElementById('the-input').disabled = false;
  }

 }, false);
 </script>

<span id="the-span">Hi, I'm the span</span>
<input id="the-input" value="I'm the input" disabled>
```

If you delete the text inside of the `span` element, and re-run the snippet, you'll see that the input box remains disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If page load is indeed your problem

If you are using jquery, paste the code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

If you are using plain js then

```
window.onload = yourfunctioncomeshere
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your are using jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var spanText = $('#SPAN_ID').text();

         //based on var spanText value you can disable/enable input

         //To disable input
         $('#INPUT_ID').attr({
                'disabled': 'disabled'
         });

         // To enable input
         if ($('#INPUT_ID').attr('disabled')) {
            $('#INPUT_ID').removeAttr('disabled');
         }
    });
```